# Splitting a data frame based on character string

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I would like to split the following data frame based on the final numbers of each element. So I would like 6 new data frames each with two elements. Here is my attempt at obtaining a data frame of the first subset containing just "ABCD-1" and "ABCC-1", but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
library("reshape2")
Barcode <- c("ABCD-1", "ABCC-1", "ABCD-2", "ABCC-2", "ABCD-3", "ABCC-3", 
"ABCD-4", "ABCC-4", "ABCD-5", "ABCC-5","ABCD-6", "ABCC-6")
bar_f <- data.frame(Barcode)
bar_f

bar_f$SampleID <- colsplit(bar_f$Barcode, pattern = "-", names = c("a","b"))$b
bar_f.s1 <- subset(barcode_file, barcode_file$SampleID == "1")
bar_f.s1
```

Can you help?

Thank you,

Abigail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is to create a factor used to define the grouping for splitting. One way is by extracting the digits pattern form the provided variable `Barcode` using regular expression. Then we convert the obtained character vector of digits to a factor with `as.factor()`. 
We can, of course, use other regular expression techniques to get the job done, or more user friendly wrapper functions from the `stringr` package, like in the second example (the `tidyverse`-ish approach).

## Example 1

A base R solution using `split`:

```r
# The provided data
Barcode <- c("ABCD-1", "ABCC-1", "ABCD-2", "ABCC-2", "ABCD-3", "ABCC-3", 
             "ABCD-4", "ABCC-4", "ABCD-5", "ABCC-5","ABCD-6", "ABCC-6")
bar_f <- data.frame(Barcode)

factor_for_split <- regmatches(x = bar_f$Barcode,
                               m = regexpr(pattern = "[[:digit:]]",
                                           text = bar_f$Barcode))
factor_for_split
#>  [1] "1" "1" "2" "2" "3" "3" "4" "4" "5" "5" "6" "6"

# Create a list of 6 data frames as asked
lst <- split(x = bar_f, f = as.factor(factor_for_split))
lst
#> $`1`
#>   Barcode
#> 1  ABCD-1
#> 2  ABCC-1
#> 
#> $`2`
#>   Barcode
#> 3  ABCD-2
#> 4  ABCC-2
#> 
#> $`3`
#>   Barcode
#> 5  ABCD-3
#> 6  ABCC-3
#> 
#> $`4`
#>   Barcode
#> 7  ABCD-4
#> 8  ABCC-4
#> 
#> $`5`
#>    Barcode
#> 9   ABCD-5
#> 10  ABCC-5
#> 
#> $`6`
#>    Barcode
#> 11  ABCD-6
#> 12  ABCC-6

# Edit names of the list
names(lst) <- paste0("df_", names(lst))

# Assign each data frame from the list to a data frame object in the global
# environment
for(name in names(lst)) {
  assign(name, lst[[name]])
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## Example 2

And, if you prefer, here is a `tidyverse`-ish approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stringr)

Barcode <- c("ABCD-1", "ABCC-1", "ABCD-2", "ABCC-2", "ABCD-3", "ABCC-3", 
             "ABCD-4", "ABCC-4", "ABCD-5", "ABCC-5","ABCD-6", "ABCC-6")
bar_f <- data.frame(Barcode)

bar_f %>% 
  mutate(factor_for_split = str_extract(string = Barcode,
                                        pattern = "[[:digit:]]")) %>% 
  group_split(factor_for_split)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Barcode factor_for_split
#>   <fct>   <chr>           
#> 1 ABCD-1  1               
#> 2 ABCC-1  1               
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Barcode factor_for_split
#>   <fct>   <chr>           
#> 1 ABCD-2  2               
#> 2 ABCC-2  2               
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Barcode factor_for_split
#>   <fct>   <chr>           
#> 1 ABCD-3  3               
#> 2 ABCC-3  3               
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Barcode factor_for_split
#>   <fct>   <chr>           
#> 1 ABCD-4  4               
#> 2 ABCC-4  4               
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Barcode factor_for_split
#>   <fct>   <chr>           
#> 1 ABCD-5  5               
#> 2 ABCC-5  5               
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Barcode factor_for_split
#>   <fct>   <chr>           
#> 1 ABCD-6  6               
#> 2 ABCC-6  6               
#> 
#> attr(,"ptype")
#> # A tibble: 0 x 2
#> # ... with 2 variables: Barcode <fct>, factor_for_split <chr>

names(lst) <- paste0("df_", 1:length(lst))
for(name in names(lst)) {
  assign(name, lst[[name]])
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Valentin! Once I type split(x = bar_f, f = as.factor(factor_for_split)), how do I then assign each to be a data frame on its own, to have 6 new data frames say bar_f1, bar_f2,...,bar_f6? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Abigail575, in that case you can use the `assign` function on each element (data.frame) of the created list with `split`. I updated my answer accordingly. It wasn't clear to me that you wanted each data frame as a separate object in the global environment. In my opinion, a more R canonical way of dealing with such cases is keeping objects in a list.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
separate(bar_f, Barcode, into = letters[1:2], sep ="-")
```

and the full `tidyvers`-way could look like

```
bar_f %>% 
  separate(Barcode, into = letters[1:2], sep ="-") %>% 
  filter(b == 1)
     a b
1 ABCD 1
2 ABCC 1
```

in base `R` you can try a `gsub` which removes letters & LETTERS and `-`

```
bar_f$SampleID <- gsub("[aA-zZ|-]","",bar_f$Barcode)
head(bar_f)
  Barcode SampleID
1  ABCD-1        1
2  ABCC-1        1
3  ABCD-2        2
4  ABCC-2        2
5  ABCD-3        3
6  ABCC-3        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another solution using built-in functions:

```
dfs <- split(bar_f, gsub("\\D", "", DT$Barcode))
names(dfs) <- paste0("df_", names(dfs))

for(nm in names(dfs)) assign(nm, dfs[[nm]])
```